# Arranging dataframe based on two columns in R

Tags: r, alternate

I have a dataframe where I have multiple data points per each participant. Two of the column variables are xmin and xmax. I computed the range of x. Every two participants are interacting, so their data should be complementary.  That is why I also have a column indicating if one is speaking or silent (ss).I am now trying to organize the participants by alternating rows based on xmin.  I have tried simple subsets, filtering, and mutating. I am now trying to do so on an individual couple (ex. participant 1 and 2). I have tried by ID and xmin and ID and ss.

Here is SAMPLE DATA:

```
VP     xmin   xmax   range   ss
001a   0      1.2    1.2     0
001a   1.2    4.7    3.5     1
001a   4.7    14.7   10.0    0
001a   14.7   40.4   25.7    1
...
001b   0      4.7    4.7     0
001b   4.7    12.8   8.1     1
001b   12.8   16.6   3.8     0
001b   16.6   18.2   1.6     1
001b   18.2   38.8   20.6    0
...
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#These were not all tried at the same time, rather I did not want to delete a line in case it worked. 

#001ab <- subset(mydata, ID == '001a' | ID == '001b')
#001ab <- interleave(001ab[001ab$ss == 0,], 001ab[001ab$ss == 1,], drop = TRUE)
#001ab <- 001ab %>% arrange(xmin & ID)
#001ab <- 001ab %>% mutate(overlap = as.integer(xmin >= lag(xmax)))
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
VP     xmin   xmax   range   ss
001a   0      1.2    1.2     0
001b   0      4.7    4.7     0
001a   1.2    4.7    3.5     1
001b   4.7    12.8   8.1     1
001a   4.7    14.7   10.0    0
001b   12.8   16.6   3.8     0
001a   14.7   40.4   25.7    1
001b   16.6   18.2   1.6     1    
...
```

I essentially want the participant IDs to alternate in rows based on the flow of a conversation (the time). Should I further subset by speaking and silences? Then, how would I alternate from there?

Comment: How about `001ab %>% arrange(xmin, ID)`?

Answer (score 2):

> ## You mentioned data.frame, so here is it in the data.frame:

```
SortedByTwoCol <- df[
  with(df, order(xmin, xmax)),
  ]
```

> ## Producing: SortedByTwoCol

```
    VP xmin xmax range ss
1 001a  0.0  1.2   1.2  0
5 001b  0.0  4.7   4.7  0
2 001a  1.2  4.7   3.5  1
6 001b  4.7 12.8   8.1  1
3 001a  4.7 14.7  10.0  0
7 001b 12.8 16.6   3.8  0
4 001a 14.7 40.4  25.7  1
8 001b 16.6 18.2   1.6  1
9 001b 18.2 38.8  20.6  0
>
```